# Error while building docker container with .net core

Tags: docker

We using docker with .net core application. When we are building the image using the build command we got the following error message.

[image]

Here is our docker file:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your dockerfile? Why are you copying your solution file? Don't you want to compile your app and only copy the result to your image?

Comment: Please see my docker file, as shown above

Comment: The error message states that the step where you copy your solution file fails because the file can't be found. Is that correct? Is your solution file located at the same place as your docker file / where you run docker build?